# Must GCP Cloud Run service account belong to same project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I am trying to deploy a Cloud Run instance in GCP using a service account from another project.  However, I am continually getting the error message:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account 
service-accounts@second-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com (or it may not exist).
```

I have given myself role Service Account User in the project that the service account belongs to, but it seems to not be working still.

Is it the case that the Cloud Run instance can only use a service account that belongs to the same project?

Comment: Have you followed this? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#using_service_accounts_in_other_projects

Comment: You can use a service account from any Google Cloud project. Your problem is that you have not granted the required IAM roles in the project you are using the service account. You are granting IAM roles (policy bindings) in the wrong project.

Comment: @JohnHanley you are saying if I have Service Account User role in project_1 and service account belongs to project_2, I can use the service account as the service account for a Cloud Run instance in project_1?

Comment: @JohnHanley I am not so sure. I have Service Account Admin and Service Account User in both projects and its still giving same error.

Comment: Show the exact command and configuration that you are using.